# How do I know that URLSession.shared.data throws an Error in Swift

Tags: swift

Below code catches an Error object "error" when the server is not available:

```swift
do{
    let (data, urlResponse) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

When I read up on the documentation of `URLSession.shared.data` it is nowhere mentioned that it also throws an error (for `URLSession.shared.dataTask` for example it states explicitly that an error item is part of the returned values).

I mean the code is working but how would I KNOW that it returns an error object? That part is absolutely not transparent to me.

Comment: The method now throws.  What is so hard to understand? It says `async throws` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/3767352-data

Comment: "how would I KNOW that it returns an error object" If it throws an error, your `catch` clause would catch it, and the error would be printed out.

Comment: Also , `dataTask` doesn't throw. It wants a `completionHandler` with an `Error` parameter.

Comment: The fact that it throws is indeed clear from the declaration. Although I agree – it is not mentioned explicitly in the documentation that the method throws apart from the keyword in declaration. Furthermore, it does not mention what errors it throws, what type. I don't find it clear as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/3767352-data) for `URLSession data(for:delegate:)` it shows the declaration as:

```
func data(
    for request: URLRequest,
    delegate: URLSessionTaskDelegate? = nil) async throws -> (Data, URLResponse
)
```

The fact that it shows `throws` tells you that you must call it with `try` which means it can throw an error that you should catch.

The `async` tells you that you must call it with `await`.

The difference with `URLSession dataTask(with:completion:)` is that `dataTask` doesn't "throw" an error. It doesn't need a `try`. The completion handler includes either the response or an `Error`.

These are two different approaches for handling errors. The old "completion" approach and the new "Swifty" async/throws approach.

Many APIs come in both flavors. If you find an Apple API that has a completion handler that returns a `Result` or some other type and an `Error` then most likely the API will also have a newer `async/throws` version.